# Create mock bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

First of all, I found solution for my problem, but I don't understand why it's working.

I've got Spring Configuration with bean:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeContext {
    @Profile("default")
    @Bean(name = Some.BEAN_NAME)
    public Some some() {
        return new SomeImpl();
    }
}
```

And the most important line in above code is: `@Profile("default")` without this line my code **don't work**.

This configuration is imported by other Spring Configuration.

I try to create test context in other place

```
@Configuration
public static class SomeTestContext extends SomeBaseTestContext {
    @Bean(name = Some.BEAN_NAME)
    public Some some() {
        return mock(Some.class);
    }
}
```

And without `@Profile("default")` debugger don't even enter test bean. It create one normal *production* bean.

So my question is: why add `@Profile("default")` resolve problem? And is any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: **why add @Profile("default") resolve problem?** - Adding where? In your test class or the configuration method? How is the test class configured?

Comment: @NaveedS adding to my configuration method - first snippet of my code.
Test class has this annotation:
`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SomeTest.SomeTestContext.class})`

Comment: When you have `@Profile("default")` specified over a `@Bean` annotated method, that method will be invoked to create the bean instance **only when** that profile is specified as active for the client (the class which uses the configuration).

Comment: @NaveedS Ok, I understand it, it's logical. But why when one bean with specific name has created, other don't? A assume, that annotation `@Primary` is for that case.

Comment: Where do you use these configuration classes? And where is the **production bean** defined? And how is it defined? Did you mean SomeImpl instance as production bean?